# Export button on Crystal Report viewer not working on server

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

Inbuilt Export and Print button in Crystal Report Produce Following Error on Server

> "Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an
>   indication that other memory is corrupt"

but it works Perfectly on Local server

```
PageLoad()
{
if(IsPostBack)
{
CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = Session["Report"];
}
}
```